# Assign the new value

Tags: python, function

I have a simple program, but I don't quite understand why the output is still 0.

```
x=0
def main():     
    getX(1,2,x)
    print(x)

def getX(v1,v2,x):
    if (v1>v2):
        v1=x
    else:
        v2=x
main()
```

Comment: Why do you think `x` will change in value? Before anything else, you are not assigning to `x` anywhere.

Comment: I thought the def getX would re-assign the X.

Comment: You need to do `x = ...` where `...` is some value or variable to assign to `x`.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue here is that `getX` does absolutely nothing. All you do is assign a value to `v1` or `v2`, both of which are local values which get discarded once the function is over.

What you probably wanted was this:

```
def getX(v1, v2):
    if v1 > v2:
        return v1
    else:
        return v2

x = getX(1, 2)
print(x)
```

`return` gives a value as the result of the function, which you can then use elsewhere. You don't need to set `x` initially or pass it to the function as it isn't used by the function at all.

Do also note that this could be solved by changing the assignments inside the function and using `global x` to access the module-level `x` you originally defined. This is bad practice as it's generally harder to follow code that modifies globals.

Comment: Thank you, the original program is from my teacher, she just want to ask why we can't change the x.

Comment: @user1718826 Just to note that if you had included that in your question about why you wanted to know it - then answers could have taken a route which would explain why that was the case, and why it's best not to change `x` like that.